# How can I prevent my sponge cake(genoise) from sinking after baking?

Tags: cake, sponge-cake

I have made a genoise sponge cake three times now. Every time when I take the cake out of the oven, it always sinks a *lot*. Like, as soon as I flip it onto the wire rack, the bottom falls about halfway. I know it won't really affect the taste or anything, but is there a method for preventing this? I know some bakers let their cakes cool in the oven, but won't that dry out the cake?

Comment: Welcome to the site! We will need your full recipe and method in order to help you figure out what's going on. How are you checking that it is done?

Comment: Hi, I know you said genoise,  but in fact the mechanism is the same in pretty much all egg-leavened cakes, so I closed as a duplicate. If you want, you can post the full recipe as the other comment suggests, so we can see if you are doing something unusual, and then we could reopen and give you advice. Please do read GdD's answer on the chiffon cake question carefully, collapse is part of the game.